# Make some characters in ListBox item underlined

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Although I have simplified the requirement slightly, I need to display some characters underlined and some not in a ListBox item - underscores are used in a string read from a database to indicate which characters need to be bold on the GUI.

For example, if a string contains "The f_at ca_t sat" then the item displayed in the ListBox will have just the a and the t underlined.

I really have no idea how to achieve this - I guess I need to define an ItemTemplate somehow but when you don't know which text is going to be underlined in advance (or even if there is any underlined text) then you cannot define <Run> elements.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't bind the `Inlines` property of a TextBlock.

You may however create an attached property with a `PropertyChangedCallback` that directly accesses the `Inlines` collection:

```
public static class TextBlockEx
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TextBlockEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, TextPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = obj as TextBlock;

        if (textBlock != null)
        {
            var text = (string)e.NewValue;

            textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
            // textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(text));
            // add Runs and Underlines as necessary here
        }
    }
}
```

Given that your ListBox is bound to a collection of strings, you would use the property in XAML like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock local:TextBlockEx.Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```